# Append difference zero to list in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I need to  take the difference of length of  `NUM1` and `ANS`  and `Num2 & ANS` and append zero equal to  the difference of length   to both `NUM1` and `NUM2`. I have trouble doing that.

```
sum(NUM1, NUM2, ANS):-
    comp(NUM1, ANS),
    comp(NUM2, ANS),
    % Arguments: Carry's from right and to left both 0 and all available digits
    add( NUM1, NUM2, ANS, 0, 0, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], _).

add( [], [], [], C, C, Digits, Digits).
comp(NUM, ANS).

comp(NUM, ANS, OUT):-
    length(NUM, L1),
    length(ANS, L2),
    LI = [0],
    (L1 < L2 -> OUT = appendlist(LI, NUM, NUM)).

appendlist([],X,X).
appendlist([X|Y],Z,[X|W]) :- append(Y,Z,W).
```

Comment: Could you please give an example? The question is ambiguous. And please remove the AI tag

Comment: if the input is {T,W,O] + {T,W,O] = [f,o,u,r] then i need to have [ 0,t,w,o] + [0,t,w,o,] = [f,o,u,r]

Comment: ie. append zero equal to length of ANS  - Length Num1 or Num2 to Num1 or Num2 respectively

Comment: i need to append at the  start

Comment: That should be a recursion of [0|tab] while the length of ANS is bigger than tab length

Comment: And please fix Your indentation. It is horribly misleading

Comment: how do i check if length of ANS is bigger than length of NUM. I know i have to something like 
While ( len(ANS) > len(NUM) )
append (o|NUM)

Answer (score 3):

This uses the Prolog `if-then-else` pattern to check the lengths of two lists. There are two output lists, which will be the same as the input lists if the lengths are the same, or one will be the shorter of the two lists prepended with zeroes to match the length of the other list.

```
make_same_length(List1, List2, NewList1, NewList2) :-
    length(List1, Len1),
    length(List2, Len2),
    (   Len1 = Len2
    ->  NewList1 = List1,
        NewList2 = List2
    ;   Len1 > Len2
    ->  NumZeroes is Len1 - Len2,
        prepend_zeroes(List2, NumZeroes, NewList2),
        List1 = NewList1
    ;   NumZeroes is Len2 - Len1,
        prepend_zeroes(List1, NumZeroes, NewList1),
        List2 = NewList2
    ).

prepend_zeroes(List, NumZeroes, PadList) :-
    length(Zeroes, NumZeroes),      % Uninstantiated list of length NumZeroes
    maplist(=(0), Zeroes),          % Unify each element of Zeroes with 0
    append(Zeroes, List, PadList).  % Prepend the zeroes to List
```

Some trivial test cases:

```
| ?- make_same_length([a,b,c], [d,e,f,g], A, B).

A = [0,a,b,c]
B = [d,e,f,g]

yes
| ?- make_same_length([a,b,c], [d,e], A, B).

A = [a,b,c]
B = [0,d,e]

yes
| ?- make_same_length([a,b], [c,d], A, B).

A = [a,b]
B = [c,d]

yes
| ?-
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code for predicate that is true if all lists in list `Out` are zero-padded lists from list `In`:

```
same_length_padded_lists(In, Out) :-
    findall(Length, (nth1(_,In,List), length(List, Length)), Lengths),
    max_list(Lengths, Max),
    length(In, Lists),
    findall(NewList, (between(1, Lists, Index), length(NewList, Max), nth1(Index, In, OL), append(Padding, OL, NewList), maplist(=(0), Padding)), Out).
```

Sample input and output:

```
?- same_length_padded_lists([[1,2], [1,2,3], [1], [5,3]], X).
X = [[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 1], [0, 5, 3]].
```

With OP's problem:

```
?- same_length_padded_lists([[T,W,O], [T,W,O], [F,O,U,R]], X).
X = [[0, _G6258, _G6261, _G6264], [0, _G6243, _G6246, _G6249], [_G6225, _G6228, _G6231, _G6234]].
```

As you see, you can pad with zeros any number of lists at once.

Comment: Nice and concise, plus general purpose. I like it.

Comment: Yes, this is a nice general solution (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that is not essentially different from @lurker's. There are 2 main differences:

1. I think it addresses the specifics of your question accurately, whereas lurker's answers shows how to solve the problem in general (I found your description hard to understand, and it took me a while to parse. I don't know whether lurker had similar trouble or was just making a wise pedagogical choice).
2. I use an extra predicate `zero_equalized_list/3` to reduce the number of conditional constructs that show up in the code.

---

```
p(L1, L2, A, Zeros_L1, Zeros_L2) :-
    length(A, Len),
    zero_equalized_list(L1, Len, Zeros_L1),
    zero_equalized_list(L2, Len, Zeros_L2).

zero_equalized_list(L, TargetLen, Zeros_L) :-
    length(L, Len),
    ( TargetLen > Len
    ->  N is TargetLen - Len,
        n_zeros_prepended(N, L, Zeros_L)
    ;   Zeros_L = L
    ).

n_zeros_prepended(N, L, Zeros_L) :-
    length(Zeros, N),
    maplist(=(0), Zeros),
    append(Zeros, L, Zeros_L).
```

2 tests:

When the first two arguments are shorter than the third:

```
?- p([1,2,3,4], [1,2,3], [1,2,3,4,5,6], X, Y).
X = [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
Y = [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3].
```

When the first two arguments are longer than the third:

```
?- p([1,2,3,4], [1,2,3], [1,2,3], X, Y).
X = [1, 2, 3, 4],
Y = [1, 2, 3].
```